# Importing csv data into mysql combining several rows of column data into multiple fields within one record

Tags: csv, mariadb, import-from-excel, mariadb-10.4

I am being supplied a CSV/XLSX file exported from a system for which I have no control. The exported CSV file can contain multiple (up to 6) rows for each patient with their different diagnosed conditions on separate rows. I am trying to import all of this data into mysql where each patient (uniquely identified by their medical record number) has all of their diagnosed conditions occupying one of six fields (condition1, condition2, ..., condition6). Is there a clever way to do this on import or do I need to import it "as-is" and then run one or more queries on the resultant table to create a new table the way I want it?

To clarify further, I have an Excel spreadsheet containing thousands of records formatted similar to:

```
| practice | provider  |   mrn   | patient  | condition  | last_visit |
| -------- | --------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 1234567 | patient1 | diagnosis1 | 2022-11-16 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 1234567 | patient1 | diagnosis2 | 2022-11-16 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 1234567 | patient1 | diagnosis3 | 2022-11-16 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 9876543 | patient2 | diagnosis1 | 2023-07-05 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 9876543 | patient2 | diagnosis2 | 2023-07-05 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 4561237 | patient3 | diagnosis1 | 2023-07-31 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 4561237 | patient3 | diagnosis2 | 2023-07-31 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 4561237 | patient3 | diagnosis3 | 2023-07-31 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 4561237 | patient3 | diagnosis4 | 2023-07-31 |
```

I am trying to import the Excel data shown above (as a CSV file) into a mysql database where each record is structured like this:

```
| practice | provider  |   mrn   | patient  | condition1 | condition2 | condition3 | condition4 | condition5 | condition6 | last_visit |
| -------- | --------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 1234567 | patient1 | diagnosis1 | diagnosis2 | diagnosis3 |            |            |            | 2022-11-16 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 9876543 | patient2 | diagnosis1 | diagnosis2 |            |            |            |            | 2023-07-05 |
| clinic1  | provider1 | 4561237 | patient3 | diagnosis1 | diagnosis2 | diagnosis3 | diagnosis4 |            |            | 2023-07-31 |
```

Comment: The normalised way to do this is to keep 1 row per condition.

Comment: The format of the CSV file is such that each medical condition associated with an individual patient is on its own row, tied to a specific patient by a common medical record number (MRN). I want to import this info into a patient record database table (one patient per record keyed by MRN) with all of the medical conditions listed in one of six condition fields. Some patients may have only one condition while others may have up to six. If a patient has less than six diagnosed medical conditions, the remaining condition fields would be blank.

Comment: To clarify please post sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: load to a staging table from . then load from staging to  final table search for  mysql pivot..

Comment: but consider the issues you would have identifying condition abc across multiple patients if it can exist in any column

Comment: P.Salmon: Based on your feedback yesterday, I decided to rethink my database and have instead implemented a many-to-many relationship between the patients table and a comprehensive conditions table using an intermediary junction/join table to tie things together. Thanks!